# Wordpress how to count custom post type by custom status

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to count custom post "job" by its status (i.e. Active Jobs).

This code showing all custom post that are published. But I want only Active Jobs. How can I do that?

```
function jb_total_jobs() { 
$total = wp_count_posts( 'job' )->publish;
return $total; 
} 
add_shortcode('total_jobs','jb_total_jobs');
```

[image: Post count]

Comment: I don't need total posts count. Above code is doing that. I want only published job that has **Active status**. You may see in the image.

Comment: Your question needs more details. How did you register your "custom status"? What arguments did you pass to `register_post_status` function. Please clarify your question.

Comment: since active is not a real status but probably a custom post meta.. what that meta field name? is it "job_status"... do you under which key its being saved to the DB?